# Nvidia + Integratid Intel + Nouveau + Ubuntu: Nvidia is not being used

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I've a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 over a MSI laptop, which includes two graphics cards: an integratel Intel and a Nvidia GeForce 840M. My intention is to install the Nvidia propietary drivers from the Nvidia website, but before the change (to do it appropriately), I want to know what is exactly happening in my computer. So, please, I don't want (now) tutorials about installing nvidia graphics, but understanding the key reason which makes my SO to use the integrated card.

Some info:

```
$ glxinfo | egrep i "renderer string|rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile
```

So, I know the integrated graphic card is the renderer. My next question is, why is the Nvidia card being ignored? Do I have the drivers installed?

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep nouveau
libdrm-nouveau2:amd64               install
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-utopic       install

$ lsmod | egrep -i "nouveau|i915"
nouveau              1206535  0 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
ttm                    93588  1 nouveau
i915                  906106  6 
drm_kms_helper         61574  2 i915,nouveau
wmi                    19193  3 msi_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
drm                   311018  7 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
video                  20128  2 i915,nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           13413  2 i915,nouveau
```

So, it shows both drivers for the integrated graphic (i915) and Nvidia (nouveau) drivers are loaded (and of course, the nouveu driver installed). Lastly:

```
$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
     description: 3D controller
     product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
     vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
     ...
 *-display
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     ...
     capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     ...
```

So, for some reason, the nouveau driver doesn't claim my Nvidia card, and the "additional drivers" menu shows me no additional drivers to install and not information at all.

What does it happen here, and who is the responsible of deciding which card must be used?

I've searched in the xorg log but I've find nothing (I don't know what to search, indeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before in many laptops. This happens because the nVidia Optimus switcher gets disabled, and as such, linux will fall back to integrated. I'm not quite sure how you'd go about re-enabling the switcher though.

It might also be helpful to note that the discreet card will still channel output through the Intel HD Graphics on the CPU